# What does File.readlines($file)[z] mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml

I am study XXE, and I clone the XXEinjector int github: https://github.com/enjoiz/XXEinjector, but I got a problem, there is a piece of code, `break if File.readlines($file)[z].chomp.empty?`, I really can't understand what does this mean, where does the [z] means??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`File#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-readlines) returns an array of lines and `z` in an index in this array.

It’s initialized [here](https://github.com/enjoiz/XXEinjector/blob/master/XXEinjector.rb#L243) and is altered [here](https://github.com/enjoiz/XXEinjector/blob/master/XXEinjector.rb#L258).

---

*Sidenote:* the code there is absolutely not ruby idiomatic and has tons of code smell. I strongly discourage you to study ruby by examining this code.

Comment: Agree, the sidenote is very important in this context.

Comment: Very well,in fact, I'm not from an English country, so I want to ask what does "tons of code smell" mean??

Comment: Basically it means every single line of code done in counter-idiomatic way.